# Limiting class' access

Tags: c++

Imagine we have the following interface:

```
class Cat {
public:
    meow() const;
    eat();
    poop();
};

class CatColony {
public:
    std::vector<Cat>& getCats() { return m_cats; }
private:
    std::vector<Cat> m_cats;
};
```

From a API design POV this is ugly, as references to private members should never be provided. Furthermore, imagine that calling `poop()` is dangerous if it `Cat` has been obtained from `CatColony`, but its OK if `Cat` has been instantiated somewhere else. In any case calling `eat()` and `meow()` do not suppose a problem. Furthermore, all methods modifying the vector itself are dangerous. What design pattern should I adopt to refactor this interface so that the concerns enumerated above disappear?

Edit: I've thought about a proxy class which limits `Cat`'s exposure. ¿Is this a good idea? ¿Even if it is more limited than the `Cat`, is it still considered as proxy?

Comment: A bit hard to tell with such an example but as you say yourself: exposing all mutable cats is ugly. So one simple (possibly naive, hard to tell with toy examples) solution is: don't do that and expose `const std::vector<Cat>& getCats()` and `CatColony::meow(const Cat& cat)`

Comment: Maybe meow() wasn't a good example as it would be a const method, however imagine in my real case it isn't, it makes the cat mutate. I'll edit the question to a better example

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear: my example doesn't require meow() or eat() to be const, it would look up that cat and see if it's really in the colony (i.e. check if it's in m_cats). It doesn't want to do anything with cats which are not part of the colony.

Comment: With passKey idiom, you might do the reverse, being sure that only `CatColony` might call a specific `Cat` method...